# Me da error al definir funciones en un archivo de origen (.cpp) de un archivo de encabezado (.h) en visual studio code

Tags: c++, vscode

Hace poco empecé a usar visual studio code para programar en C++. En un principio todo iba bien, el típico "hola mundo" se compilaba correctamente con g++, pero al introducir objetos han empezado a surgir errores.

Más específicamente al declarar las funciones de un archivo de encabezado de una clase en un .cpp.

Este es el código que estoy probando:

El .cpp donde está la funcion main

```
#include "Punto.h"

int main()
{
    Punto* p = new Punto(1, 1);

    delete p; 

    return 0;
}
```

El .h de la clase Punto

```
#pragma once

class Punto
{
public:

    Punto(int _x, int _y);

    int getX();

    int getY();

    void setX(int _x);

    void setY(int _y);

private:

    int x;

    int y;
};
```

El .cpp de la clase Punto

```
#include "Punto.h"

Punto::Punto(int _x, int _y)
{
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
}

int Punto::getX()
{
    return x;
}

int Punto::getY()
{
    return y;
}

void Punto::setX(int _x)
{
    x = _x;
}

void Punto::setY(int _y)
{
    y = _y;
}
```

EL error que me da al compilar:

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbh5L9k.o: en la función `main': prueba.cpp:(.text+0x2a): referencia a` Punto::Punto(int, int)' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: ¿Tienes todos los ficheros en el mismo directorio? ¿Qué compilador estás empleando?

Comment: Están todos en el mismo fichero y estoy usando el compilador G++. Para compilar este proyecto estoy escribiendo en la terminal "g++ -o prueba prueba.cpp"

Comment: Tienes que añadir el cpp donde tengas las definiciones de la clase punto para que funcione. Suponiendo que se llame `Punto.cpp`, tendrias que compilar con `g++ -o prueba prueba.cpp Punto.cpp`. Una nota, cuando contestes los comentarios añade un `@usuario` para que le llegue la respuesta

Comment: @Pablochaches Funcionó, pero me pregunto si hay alguna forma de compilar todos los archivos a la vez, ya que si tengo 1000 clases no me parece viable escribir el nombre de todos los archivos en la orden de compilación.

Comment: Tantos archivos ya no lo gestionas tu manualmente, eso seria una pesadilla horrible. Para proyectos mas grandes el trabajo de juntar y compilar los archivos se lo pasas a un build sistem. Hechale un vistazo a `make` y `cmake`.